# Filtering rows of count matrix with `rowSums` gives error 'x' must be numeric

Tags: r, matrix, filtering, read.table

I have a count matrix in `.csv` format. The data is structured like this:

| Genes | cond. 1 | cond. 2 | cond. 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alpha | 77 | 51 | 98 |
| Beta | 0 | 0 | 71 |
| Cena | 823 | 856 | 0 |

I'm trying to filter out the matrix where the new matrix will have rows with a sum that is above 0.

To filter out the rows whose sum is 0, I wrote the code in this way:

```
Counts <- Count[which(rowSums(Counts) > 0), ]
```

but it gave me an error saying:

```
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for 
  function 'which': 'x' must be numeric
```

I checked the data to see if there were any NA's but there were none. There are only numeric numbers.

Here is my full code:

```
Counts <- read.delim("RiboTag_count_matrix_10-05-2023.csv", 
                     header = TRUE, sep=",")

Counts  ## shows the matrix visually

Counts <- Counts[which(rowSums(Counts > 0,]  ## filter out rows with 0's
```

I'm not sure where in my code it produced an error. Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

I even tried

```
## Convert Counts to a matrix
Counts <- as.matrix(Counts)

## Convert them to numeric
Counts <- apply(Counts, 2, as.numeric)

# Check for and handle missing values
if (any(is.na(Counts))) {
  ## Handle missing values (e.g., replace with 0)
  Counts[is.na(Counts)] <- 0
}
```

to troubleshoot my problem but still gave me same error message.

Comment: The `Genes` column isn’t numeric. You could instead try `Counts <- Counts[rowSums(Counts[, -1]) > 0, ]` to omit the first column from `rowSums()`. Also note you don’t need `which()`; you can just directly index with the logical vector.

Comment: @zephryl Be careful with the `which`, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Wait,** you try to drink the coffee without milk, but buy it with milk first and take it out later.

#### Use `read.delim` properly

In documentation `?read.delim` further down in section "CSV files" we read,

> the commonest form of CSV file with row names needs to be read with
> `read.csv(..., row.names = 1)` to use the names in the first column of the file as row names,

which also applies to `read.delim`. In section just above we learn, the *Value* we get is a `data.frame`, and need doing `as.matrix()` to get a matrix.

So to get the `matrix` with desired integers and row and column names, do

```
(Counts <- read.delim('foo.csv', row.names=1) |> as.matrix())
#         cond.1 cond.2 cond.3
# Alpha       77     51     98
# Beta         0      0     71
# Gamma      823    856      0
# Delta        0      0      0
# Epsilon     59     NA      1

class(Counts)
# [1] "matrix" "array" 
typeof(Counts)
# [1] "integer"
```

and everything is fine.

<sub>*Note:* If your .csv file is actually comma separated, use `read.csv` instead; your use of `sep=','` confuses me a little.</sub>

#### The thing with the `which`

`which` "cares" for `NA`s. (I've added one in the *Epsilon* row to demonstrate.)

While using `which` also removes rows with `NA`s,

```
Counts[which(rowSums(Counts) > 0), ] 
#       cond.1 cond.2 cond.3
# Alpha     77     51     98
# Beta       0      0     71
# Gamma    823    856      0
```

not using it, fails.

```
Counts[rowSums(Counts) > 0, ] 
#       cond.1 cond.2 cond.3
# Alpha     77     51     98
# Beta       0      0     71
# Gamma    823    856      0
# <NA>      NA     NA     NA
```

However, you may want to decide if you really want to remove these rows, or do something else with them, e.g. impute or check where the `NA` comes from in the first place.

#### Appendix

`matrix`es, unlike `data.frame`s can only contain one `typeof` data, e.g. either numeric (integer, double) or character. If we had a numeric matrix `m`,

```
(m <- matrix(0, 2, 2))
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    0    0
# [2,]    0    0

typeof(m)
# [1] "double"
```

and change only one element to character,

```
m[1, 2] <- 'A'
m
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,] "0"  "A" 
# [2,] "0"  "0"
```

we get a character matrix,

```
typeof(m)
# [1] "character"
```

which was the case with your `Count` matrix.

---

*Data:*

*foo.csv* file:

```
"cond.1"    "cond.2"    "cond.3"
"Alpha" 77  51  98
"Beta"  0   0   71
"Gamma" 823 856 0
"Delta" 0   0   0
"Epsilon"   59  NA  1
```

or alternatively

```
"Genes" "cond.1"    "cond.2"    "cond.3"
"Alpha" 77  51  98
"Beta"  0   0   71
"Gamma" 823 856 0
"Delta" 0   0   0
"Epsilon"   59  NA  1
```