# How to avoid blank data frame using which statement in R

Tags: r

In the following example, I can filter out rows equal to `a` by using `-which`.

```
x = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b")
z = as.numeric(c(8,8,8,8,8,8))
data_input = data.frame(cbind(x, z))
data_input[-which(data_input$x == "a"), ]

  x z
4 b 8
5 b 8
6 b 8
```

However, if I set the value to `c` (as part of data check: c doesn't exist all the time, sometimes it exists and I want to take it out; if not, then keep the data as is), then it will produce a blank data frame. Instead I expect it to return the original data frame. How can I achieve that, please? Thanks.

```
> data_input[-which(data_input$x == "c"), ]
[1] x z
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Comment: Don't use `which()`, just use a logical vector, e.g. `data_input[data_input$x != "a", ]` / `data_input[data_input$x != "c", ]`.

Comment: `data.frame(cbind(x, z))` is a wrong way to create a dataframe. It forces all columns to be the same type. You can check `str(data_input)` to see that `z` is no longer numeric. You should use `data.frame(x, z)` instead.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento I'd consider "not-using-`which`" as a myth, wrote a related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77248430/6574038) on that a while ago.

Comment: @jay.sf - It wasn't meant to be taken as a blanket statement against the use of `which()` - it certainly has its place.  Just in this case OP went past an approach that worked for their purposes and accidentally turned it into an approach that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You may write a custom function to handle this :

```
remove_data <- function(data, value) {
  inds <- data$x %in% value
  if(any(inds)) {
    data <- data[!inds, ]
  }
  return(data)
}
remove_data(data_input, "a")

#  x z
#4 b 8
#5 b 8
#6 b 8

remove_data(data_input, "c")

#  x z
#1 a 8
#2 a 8
#3 a 8
#4 b 8
#5 b 8
#6 b 8
```

Answer (score 1):

This is very straightforward if we are using `dplyr`, just use `filter`, and negate (`!`) the equallity (`==`):

```
library(dplyr)

filter(data_input, !a == "a")

  x z
1 b 8
2 b 8
3 b 8

filter(data_input, !a == "c")

  x z
1 a 8
2 a 8
3 a 8
4 b 8
5 b 8
6 b 8
```